# Installing software without administrative role

Tags: deployment

How can I give authorization to install software on a PC that is on the Domain to a tech without giving the Administrator role? Using Windows server 2008 R2

Comment: A lot of SW can be installed be "Power User" privs, which is less then Admin. I also think that a lot of software can be installed by user because it's msi is digitally signed. This is Active Directory related stuff.

Comment: Power Users on SERVERS?

Comment: No power user, The Tech is a user with backup role & account creation role. How would I create a power user?

Comment: @Ivan Power Users has been deprecated for years and should not be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can not. On servers installation of software is defined as an administrator's act.

Comment: The software is not being installed on the server, it's being installed on PC connected to the server.

Comment: Then Power Users role on the computer should be able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you aren't aware..  You can grant users administrator access on the local PCs without granting them admin access on the domain or servers.  You don't need to fiddle around with power users or anything if what you are really trying to do is setup privileges for some helpdesk techs to fix the local desktops without granting them the ability to mess up your servers.

You seem to want to grant give users the ability to perform administrative actions on the workstations, so just in case you weren't aware that you can do this without granting domain privileges here is what you do.

Just create Domain group called Something like 'Workstation Admins', add the user to the 'Workstation Admins' group, then use a group policy linked into the OU with all your user desktops/workstations/laptos to add the 'Workstation Admins' group you created to the local administrators group on the workstations.